# Facebook API: How to access user data when the user is offline?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I'm writing an app that keeps track of a user's friends. I want to be able to verify his friend list when he isn't online. Is there a way to do this? In other words, do API calls again an account that was verified while the user is offline?

Comment: Haven't worked with FB API for a while but back then there was an "offline access" permission the user had to grant to your app in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a long-lived `access_tokens` to access Facebook on a user's behalf for a period of up to 6 months. This means you can access the user's friend list or perform other operations as long as the user logs in one in a while.

[This tutorial covers how to get a long-lived access token using the Facebook PHP SDK](https://www.webniraj.com/2013/09/17/facebook-api-getting-a-long-lived-access-token/).